# How to create a list in SharePoint 2010 and perform basic CRUD operations?

Tags: list

I am new to SharePoint 2010, can you please help me to create a SharePoint list and basic CRUD operations?

Answer (score 2):

To create a list:

```
 Guid newListId = site.Lists.Add("My Custom List", "This list was created programmatically", site.ListTemplates["Custom List"]);
 //This is optional = just to get the list and put it on the left navigation.
 SPList newList = site.Lists[newListId];
 newList.OnQuickLaunch = true;
 newList.Update();
```

To create, update and delete list items:

```
 SPListItem itm = myList.Items.Add();
 itm["Title"] = "Test Item";
 itm["Data 1"] = "Flamingo";
 itm.Update();
 //*** Update the item
 itm["Data 1"] = "Dalmation";
 itm.Update();
 //*** Delete the item
 itm.Delete();
```

To get an item:
SPListItem itm = myList.GetItemById( itemId );

You can also use SPQuery to get a list item or many items.

A long time ago I wrote about [how to perform some of these basic tasks](http://www.novolocus.com/?s=%22WSS%20Practice%22) in some blog posts.

Comment: This answer definitely points out the basics. However, its worth pointing out that if a user does not has permissions to create list, create list item, edit list item, or delete list items, etc., SP will throw ugly errors. I learned this the hard way. Almost every object in SP has a .doesUserHasPermissions() method. You should definitely play around with that. It will help you write more robust code.

Answer (score 0):

Very much depend on how you want to create that list.

- As enduser through UI
- As developer programmatically
- As IT-Pro using powershell

If it's as an end-user the

- Click Site Actions
- click View All Site Content
- click Create

For more options see [Create or delete a list](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/create-or-delete-a-list-HA010377306.aspx)